# Apply javascript function to same ids

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to ask let say if we have multiple divs with same id how can we display none them using javascript ?

I tried:

```
<script>
function filterfunc() { 
if(document.getElementById('filter_deductible').value == 'id_50'){

document.getElementById('id_0').style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('id_50').style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
```

And here is my html divs with same ids:

```
<div id="id_0">0</div>
<div id="id_0">0</div>
<div id="id_50">50</div>
```

But its hidding only one div of id id_0 instead of all div having id_0

Any suggestions please

Comment: Your problem is your title

Comment: Apply class instead. You should have unique id's in your code!

Comment: Two elements, same ID? Bad idea.

Comment: IDs are suppose to be unique. Thats why they are called `ID`s.

Comment: Why is everyone using jQuery while the OP is using plain JavaScript his question? Just because the jQuery tag?

Comment: @GuyT Then why OP selected `jQuery` TAG?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Probably because he has more views when he uses that tag. FYI: JavaScript solution http://jsfiddle.net/yt29u87e/

Comment: @GuyT That doesn't make any sense. The javascript tag has much more questions and followers, and if you tag wrong you'll just get irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simple using jQuery like

**HTML**

```
<select name="filter_deductible" id="filter_deductible">
    <option value="id_0">0</option>
    <option value="id_50">50</option>
</select>
<div id="id_0">0</div>
<div id="id_0">0</div>
<div id="id_50">50</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#filter_deductible").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="id_50")
  {
    $('[id="id_0"]').hide();
  }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P2j3f/150/)**

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique, you should use class like,

```
<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_50">50</div>
```

And to hide all `id_0` use

```
function filterfunc() { 
    if($('#filter_deductible').val() == 'id_50'){
       $('div.id_0').hide();
       $('div.id_50').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a class in case there are multiple elements. Or use different ids.

Ids are meant to be unique.

```
<script>
function filterfunc() { 
if(document.getElementById('filter_deductible').value == 'id_50'){

$('.id_0').css("display","none")

$('.id_50').css("display","block")
}
}
</script>


<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_50">50</div>
```

Or

```
 <script>
    function filterfunc() { 
    if(document.getElementById('filter_deductible').value == 'id_50'){

    $('.id_0').hide()

    $('.id_50').css("display","block")
    }
    }
    </script>


    <div class="id_0">0</div>
    <div class="id_0">0</div>
    <div class="id_50">50</div>
```

Comment: What is `$('.id_0').style`?

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** do this. Having multiple elements with the same ids leads to undefined behaviour. If you need to attach information to your dome nodes use data attributes or classes.
Notice how `getElementById` is singular form? It only ever expects to select and return one element.

That being said, you can probably get away with

```
document.querySelectorAll("#id_0")
```

Comment: No but `document.querySelectorAll("[id=id_0]")` would work even anyway this is just wrong to use duplicate IDs just as you mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use javascript functions on dom elements you have to use class not id attribute.

id attribute is unique in whole html document.

try to use jquery.

```
$.(document).ready(function(){
   $("#filter_deductible").change(function(){
       var $this = $(this); //instance of element where was changed value
       if($this.val() == 'id_50'){
           $(".id_0").hide();
           $(".id_50").show();
       }
   });
});
```

your document html should looks like.

```
<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_0">0</div>
<div class="id_50">50</div>
```

this will works only if you will include jquery library inside  tags. And your dom element #filter_deductible allows change event trigger.

hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use classes in this case ID is unique.

```
<div class="zero">0</div>
<div class="zero">0</div>
<div class="class_50">50</div>
```

you can use jQuery:

```
$('.zero').hide();
$('.class_50').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML spec requires that the ID attribute to be unique in a page:

If you want to have several elements with the same ID your code will not work as the method getElementByID only ever returns one value and ID's need to be unique. If you have two ID's with the same value then your HTML is invalid.

What you would want to do is use div class="id_0" and use the method getElementsByClassName as this returns an Array of elements

```
function filterFunc() {
    var n = document.getElementsByClassName("id_0");
    var a = [];
    var i;
    while(n) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the Element
        // This returns as many Elements that exist with this class name so `enter code here`you can set each value as       visible.
    }   

}
```